# Force.com IDE isn't storing passwords

Tags: ide

I recently installed the latest version of Eclipse (eclipse-java-kepler-R, 2.0.1.20130919-0803) with the Force.com IDE plugin (29.0.0.201310181333).  Everything was working fine until this morning, when it had lost the credentials for the project I was working on.

I could re-enter the password and security token, the plugin connected to Salesforce, but as soon as I closed the Force.com IDE settings on the project and re-opened it, the credentials were gone.

Logging into Salesforce, and going to the Login History of my account, I saw the plugin connecting just fine.

How can I get it to start storing the passwords again?

Comment: I haven't worked on the Salesforce platform in a long time, but it amazes me that this question and answer still get upvotes over 5 years after I wrote them.  How has this bug remained in Eclipse or Salesforce plugins for so long?!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I found a solution.  I had to go into the Eclipse preferences and delete the values in "Secure Storage".

1. Select the `Window/Preferences` item.
2. Go to `General/Security/Secure Storage`.
3. Select the `Contents` tab.
4. Select `Force Projects` and then click the `Delete` button.

After restarting, Force.com IDE was able to save my passwords again.

Comment: Eclipse was doing this to me earlier, so I switched to Mavens Mate.. Oh well

Comment: Awesome answer, probably saved me half a day of hunting around, trying different things, thanks.

Comment: Brilliant!  If I could give you more than 1 upvote, I would

Answer (score 4):

I ended up doing something similar but a little different to resolve the issue.  I'm listing the steps I followed here in case any other Mac users are seeing this issue after making keychain changes:

Earlier this afternoon I reset the login keychain on my Mac; when I later went to refresh files in the Force.com IDE, I found that my Force.com project passwords were no longer being stored.  I started to follow @tomlogic's instructions, but when I got to the General/Security/Secure Storage section, I noticed on the Password tab that there was a value "OS X Keystore Integration" that was prioritized the highest in the "Master password providers" list.  I unchecked this and was then asked to enter a master password - something I had never been asked to do before.  I entered it and saved, and everything seems back to normal now.