# Force.com IDE not storing salesforce credential

Tags: eclipse, ide

Using Eclipse Kepler and when I add a new project, and after retrieving required components, I am trying to save the file to server and getting "unable to login error" I checked project properties and observed that my password field is blank. I enter password again, it asks me to refresh the content in workspace. I click ok and again same problem. After updating I immediately go to project properties and see that my password is again wiped. Anyone faced this issue. Please let me know if more information is required to complete this question.

I tried with username and password of multiple orgs and the behaviour is same. I also tried changing workspace path and created new project. Again the same behaviour.

Followed the best answer on Question # 19366 [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19366/force-com-ide-isnt-storing-passwords). But I dont have any content in security storage. Please refer below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force.com IDE isn't storing passwords](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19366/force-com-ide-isnt-storing-passwords)

Comment: Adrian, I dont have any values in security storage. Please see attached screenshot(just updated the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate Question:

Please refer to the workaroud here

[Force.com IDE isn't storing passwords](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19366/force-com-ide-isnt-storing-passwords)

Comment: I dont have any values in security storage. Please see attached screenshot(just updated the question)

Comment: Click on the 'Force Project' and delete that entry. Next time onwards password will be saved.

Comment: Thanks blackwind I lost sight of it. Worked perfectly now.